# How to highlight a room in 2d sheet of Autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to highlight a room in 2D sheet in Autodesk forge viewer. For example, in the below 2D sheet I need to highlight one of the rooms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the rooms in the sheet can be selected like below, then you can just call `viewer.select( roomDbId )` to highlight it. On the contrary, if it can not be selected by mouse-click, then you must set up the [room color scheme](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-669094D5-FE7D-4F72-8B09-7BB45479535B) for each room with non-white colors.

[image]